# I need a sql query that retrieves the result as multiple columns from a single column values

Tags: sql, pivot

The Table structure is as follows:

```
id |det_Id | Name | Value
```

Sample data is as follows:

```
1 | 111 | A | Apple

2 | 111 | B | Ball

3 | 111 | C | Cat

4 | 222 | A | Air

5 | 222 | B | Badge

6 | 222 | C | Car
```

I am trying to return the A, B, C as separate columns in one SQL statement.

My expected output is:

```
111 | Apple | Ball |Cat

222 | Air   | Badge|Car
```

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Your first approach can be to join the table with itself on the `det_Id`. Did you try anything so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: That is called a PIVOT.

Comment: I tried by using case statement .like

Answer (score 1):

Use the `PIVOT` function.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT det_Id, Name, Value FROM yourtable) a
PIVOT
(MIN(Value) FOR Name IN ([A], [B], [C]))b
```

Output

```
det_Id A     B     C
111    Apple Ball  Cat
222    Air   Badge Car
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c02dd8/2/0